# case vs method builders, using named default parameters

Tags: scala, builder, factory-pattern

I was about to use case classes with named default parameters as builders. For a simple example:

```
case class Person(name:String)
case class PersonBob(name:String = "Bob") {
   def build = Person(name)
}
val casePerson = PersonBob("case").build
```

But I could use methods as well:

```
object Builder {
  def personBob(name:String = "Bob"):Person = Person(name)
}
val methodPerson = Builder.personBob("method")
```

Some tradeoffs:

- Method approach eliminates the need to create an object for each builder...saving cycles and memory.
- Method approach has a bit leaner implementation code. No advantage for the usage syntax.
- Methods can't be passed in as parameters to other builders for "builder composition". Functions can, but we are talking about methods here since functions don't support parameter defaults.
- Case class approach allows me to persist builder instances (not needed now).
- Case class approach would facilitate building an internal DSL at some point--but I think an external DSL is ambivalent to either approach.

Other considerations? Build a better builder some other way?

Comment: There's no reason to use a builder for the example you have given, a simple factory method would suffice. If you need more complex object building, please provide an example on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Confused am I:  isn't the baked-in case class factory all that you need here, or am I missing something.  IOW:

```
scala> case class Foo(bar:String="ab")
defined class Foo

scala> val f = Foo()
f: Foo = Foo(ab)

scala> f.bar
res2: String = ab
```

Comment: In this case I building domain objects from classes in another library that I can't alter. So I have to create separate builders.